# Derivatives of "Fresh" use?

Tags: word-usage

**1. ____________, the party's current spokesman is very frank.**

**2. She tore up the letter and started ____________.**

These two blank spaces should be filled with a derivative form of the word ***Fresh***.
Does anyone know the word? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm not 100% of what meaning you're trying to convay with the first sentence, but might I suggest you're looking for [afresh](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/afresh) (synonomous to the more formal "anew").

Comment: *Being fresh* in the first one? I can think of no *single* word that would work.